# how to use jquery this keyword in angular 8 component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

i am using jquery in angular 8 component ts and i want add class on clicked event. So i need to call this keyword.

```
activeSideMenu(){
      jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
        $('#mySidenav a').on('click',() => {
          var ths = this;
          $('#mySidenav a').removeClass('active');
          $(ths).addClass('active');
          console.log('hello')
        })
      });
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered pure Angular solution. You shoud have strong reasons to use jQuery with Angular together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Sir i am begginner in angular so i have use jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use jQuery at all. I suspect that you want to have active class on menu item based on your current url. You can use

```
[routerLinkActive]="'active'"
```

on your  element with routerLink. It will add 'active' class when that route is active

Comment: Can you share html for your navigation?

Comment: Sorry for last comment there is my fault. Actually this is working. but this is not working on without routerLInk. I want for all. `<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" *ngIf="router.url != '/login'">
  <a href="#" class="mt-3" routerLink="/devices" [routerLinkActive]="'active'" (click)="closeNav()">
    </a>
  <a (click)="toggle = !toggle; opn()" [routerLinkActive]="'active'" >
    </a>
</div>`

Comment: You should use routerLink for navigation in Angular application

Comment: I dont need link on some <a> tags. But you solved my 50% problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" *ngIf="router.url != '/login'">
    <a class="mt-3" routerLink="/devices" [routerLinkActive]="active" (click)="closeNav()"> Devices</a>
    <a (click)="toggle = !toggle; opn()" [ngClass]="toggle ? 'active' : ''">Open </a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is half working because this is not removing another selected class.